# Javascript: How do I append a string to Google search query?

Tags: javascript, append, jscript

I want to programmatically append `+test1+test2+test3` to `https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=`

Fiddler captured this web session:

[image]

I tried this code, but it's not working

```
if (oSession.uriContains("www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=")) 
        {
            var str = oSession.fullUrl;
            var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
            if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
            {
                oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: How does it "not work"? What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the current output?

Comment: Ehh... at first you say "it's not working", then a couple of lines later you say "it works". This is confusing, whatever "work" is meaning. Also, there seems not to be JavaScript in the linked screenshot.

Comment: I want to programmtically add `+test1+test2+test3` to `www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=`. And what do you mean by `current output`?

Comment: @Teemu its not adding `+test1+test2+test3` to the URL

Comment: You're hiding too much information. What is `oSession`, and from what library it's coming from?

Comment: @Teemu The code is JScript .NET, which is basically a .NET version of Javascript.Regardless of language, Anyone with appending type of skill can answer my question.